# How to list active / open connections in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Is there any hidden table, system variable or something to show active connections in a given moment?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use the [`V$SESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223) view.

> `V$SESSION` displays session information for each current session.

Comment: Error starting at line 1 in command:
select * from FROM v$session
Error at Command Line:1 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Either you don't have permissions, or you didn't install the DBA views correctly.

Comment: You'll need the select_catalog_role role.

Comment: You can join v$sqltext to get the current SQL of sessions too.

Comment: pistacchio, you have 2 "from FROM" in the SQL: "select * from FROM v$session"

Comment: @Alkini, over which fields should I run the join? I couldn't find any similar fields on both tables

Comment: Before running queries on `V_$SESSION`, you need to grant access for your user. Run the following query using your sysadmin user: `GRANT SELECT ON V_$SESSION TO username;`

Answer (score 131):

For a more complete answer see:
   http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=16834

```
select
       substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
       substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
       substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
       substr(b.machine,1,6) box,
       substr(b.username,1,10) username,
--       b.server,
       substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
       substr(b.program,1,30) program
from v$session b, v$process a
where
b.paddr = a.addr
and type='USER'
order by spid;
```

Comment: The substr feels unnecessary

Answer (score 36):

When I'd like to view incoming connections from our application servers to the database I use the following command:

```
SELECT username FROM v$session 
WHERE username IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY username ASC;
```

Simple, but effective.

Answer (score 8):

```
Select count(1) From V$session
where status='ACTIVE'
/
```

Answer (score 8):

```
select s.sid as "Sid", s.serial# as "Serial#", nvl(s.username, ' ') as "Username", s.machine as "Machine", s.schemaname as "Schema name", s.logon_time as "Login time", s.program as "Program", s.osuser as "Os user", s.status as "Status", nvl(s.process, ' ') as "OS Process id"
from v$session s
where nvl(s.username, 'a') not like 'a' and status like 'ACTIVE'
order by 1,2
```

This query attempts to filter out all background processes.

Answer (score 5):

```
select
  username,
  osuser,
  terminal,
  utl_inaddr.get_host_address(terminal) IP_ADDRESS
from
  v$session
where
  username is not null
order by
  username,
  osuser;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some intuition for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
select status, count(1) as connectionCount from V$SESSION group by status;
```

Answer (score 4):

The following gives you list of operating system users sorted by number of connections, which is useful when looking for excessive resource usage.

```
select osuser, count(*) as active_conn_count 
from v$session 
group by osuser 
order by active_conn_count desc
```

---

**SQL> select osuser, count(*) as active_conn_count from v$session  group by osuser;**

OSUSER                         ACTIVE_CONN_COUNT

---

tepadm                                        20
oracle                                        39

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    count(1) "NO. Of DB Users", 
    to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') sys_time
from 
    v$session 
where 
    username is NOT  NULL;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

---check active seeeion---

SQL> **SELECT SID, Serial#, UserName, Status, SchemaName, Logon_Time
FROM V$Session
WHERE
Status='ACTIVE' AND
UserName IS NOT NULL;**

```
   SID    SERIAL# USERNAME                       STATUS   SCHEMANAME                     LOGON_TIM
```

---

```
   247      28849 SYS                            ACTIVE   SYS                            11-JAN-23
   251      27524 SAPSR3                         ACTIVE   SAPSR3                         11-JAN-23
```