# Oracle DB function log file

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper

I executed a script in unix that called a function in oracle db. I didn't gave the logfile information for the unix script. Usually, when I run a script to call a db function, I give logfile for script and monitor the unix log file and know that if the function is still running or is done. Also, the logfile has information whether the function executed successfully or not.

I have following concerns, based on above situation:

1. Can I monitor if the function is still running or not using oracle sql developer?
2. Can I know if the funtion executed successfully in Oracle DB or not? If oracle saves a log of function execution and I could access that then it would be great.

Thank You

Comment: Do you actually mean function, or do you mean procedure?  Functions are called as part of a query, procedures are called on their own with `EXECUTE`.

Comment: The unix script has following line to call the function:       `exec :v_return_nbr := function(parameters);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can monitor if the function is still running by checking the session's status in `v$session`.  See this answer for information on how: [How to list active / open connections in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043096/477563)

As for what the execution result was... probably not.
The PL/SQL you executed won't directly appear in `dba_audit_trail`, but any queries it ran as part of execution might.  The audit trail will show if the queries were successful or not, but it won't show the query results or the final result of the function execution.