# Oracle query to determine data sources (external and internal) for Tables and MViews in a schema?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

So lets say I provide my customers a schema in Oracle on which they can access data {as views based on my table and its data (which is in another schema)} and also they use third party sources/connections to get more data for their tables, MViews etc.

Is there anyway to determine these connections/ data sources?
Any queries to help me determine it? Maybe the amount of data they use? or even just the connections?

I tried to look up the internet, but couldn't find much.

I am looking into this, but its not the proper solution.

```
select
       substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
       substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
       substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
       substr(b.machine,1,6) box,
       substr(b.username,1,10) username,
--       b.server,
       substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
       substr(b.program,1,30) program
from v$session b, v$process a
where
b.paddr = a.addr
and type='USER'
order by spid;
```

I found it here,
[How to list active / open connections in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043096/how-to-list-active-open-connections-in-oracle)